# copy or move replace file and update version sharepoint CSOM

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint, csom

hi im using method for copy or move file on sharepoint. but i want to ask how to implement when it's duplicated it automatically replace and update version?

i've been try with this function but it's always

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'The destination file
> already exists

```
public void CopyFile(string SrcUrl, string DestUrl)
    {
        MoveCopyOptions option = new MoveCopyOptions();
        option.KeepBoth = false;
        MoveCopyUtil.CopyFile(this.clientContext,SrcUrl,DestUrl,true,option);
        this.clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

And my src

```
http://win-e636ggi1v13:55555/sites/srsrms/SRS%20Documents/Finance/fredytest/License%20Management.csv
```

and my Destination file

```
http://win-e636ggi1v13:55555/sites/srsrms/SRS%20Documents/Finance/paidi/Finance%20Folder/License%20Management.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

@Mister Fredy,

Please set 'KeepBoth' to false and keep 'Overwrite' with true.

With the above settings, it will overwrite the existing file.

When both are false, it will prompt below error:

[image]

Another scenario is :

the destination file is not overwritten and a new file with a duplicate avoiding filename is created - i.e. a number is appended to the filename to avoid a duplicate.

BR

Comment: hi i already change keep both to false and overwrite with true but still cannot overwrite and return destination file already exists

Comment: which version of sp you're using?  the above test i performed is on sp online.

Comment: im using sharepoint 2016. and for csom version is 16.1.20412.12000